# Saving check state checkbox html in XML file

Tags: php, html

I want to made a simple check list with html.

`<input type="checkbox" name="" value="">   <br>`

It won't be a massive list.
But the problem is, surely, it won't saved, except it was stored on a persistence.
Although I can add connection to a MySQL database, this time I just don't want to use MySQL at all.
So I was planning to save those checkbox states on a permanent file.
Not on `$_SESSION`. 
Do you have any idea what should I do?

Comment: If you are working in PHP, can't you just create a separate PHP file that contains all your `<input>`s and then use an `<?php include("myInputs.php"); ?>` to pull them in?

Comment: how to save/edit/modify that myInput.php? can you give me an example?

Comment: Well, you would save/edit/modify that file just like any other PHP file you create (i.e. index.php).  Probably with a text editor or IDE.